# Jquery .off and then restore it to on

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

When i want to remove the click handler from my submit button,I am using

```
$(#submitBtn).off();//works fine
```

But,when I want to restore back to its previous stage,`.on()` doesnt work.

```
                if(flag){
               $(#submitBtn).off();//works fine
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'someservice.php',
                    data: {email:email,name:name,text:text},
                    success: function (data) {
                       $('#submitBtn').on();//does not work
                });//ajax end
            }
```

Comment: You have to specify about the function that you want to bind again..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy is there no other way of doing it?

Comment: Show us the initial event binding for the button `#submitBtn`

Comment: `.off()` works because, it unbinds all the events on that object, just `on()` won't work, because you have to specifically mention the event to bind.

Answer (score 1):

**[.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**

> Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names.

**[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. And it must have arguments -

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

---

Instead of binding and unbinding, I suggest you use button disabling logic : `.prop('disabled')`

```
$('#submitBtn').prop('disabled',true)         //disable
$('#submitBtn').prop('disabled',false)        //enable
```

*Note* : The ID selector is written as `$('#submitBtn')` and not `$(#submitBtn)`

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the event so when you call `on()` you need to specify which event since it won't know about it.

`$('#submitBtn').on('click', someFn);`

You could also disable the button to prevent multiple submits and then remove the disabled attribute in your ajax success handler

Comment: how can i disable the button?I mean which will be the better way to go..off() or disabling the button?

Comment: Disabling the button is probably better. There will be a visual indication (it will be grey) and there won't be any feedback when the user clicks on it.

Comment: i could have used the event.preventDefault but that gives probblem considering that site is responsive,my submit button is an image